# How to filter parts of a string from an arraylist

Tags: java, regex

I have an `ArrayList<String> listWithoutDuplicates` which stores the elements like this:

```
[java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getInstance( alg);, java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getInstance( alg _);, java.security.AlgorithmParameters.init( params);, java.security.AlgorithmParameters.init( parAr);, java.security.AlgorithmParameters.init( parAr _);, parsRes = java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getEncoded();, parsRes = java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getEncoded( format);]
```

I'm trying to extract the following output and store this in another `List`:

```
getInstance( alg) 
getInstance( alg _)
init( params)
init( parAr)
init( parAr _)
getEncoded()
getEncoded( format)
```

I tried to use the replace the `.` with `,` and now I'm trying to get every part which is before `;`.

```
String sat = listWithoutDuplicates.toString().replace(".", ",");
List<String> answer = Arrays.asList(sat.split(";"));
```

Could somebody please help me with this. 
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

```java
str.replaceAll("(.*);", "$1");
```

should get you everything before the ; (note this is on a single string, not each str in the array)

This makes use of the grouping property of regex (regular expression). If you don't know regex, then I HIGHLY recommend you go read some tutorials and try it out. (note: most different implementations are slightly different, so you'll have to learn the principles behind it and then learn the 'syntax sugar' of each implementation (which language/framework) as you go.)